# ffmpeg rtmp streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, red5, rtmp

I have Red5 oflaDemo Connected and working fine

When I try to **rtmp stream flv file with ffmpeg** I am getting this **errors**

```
root@zzz-OptiPlex-170L:~# ffmpeg -re -i '/usr/share/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams
/avatar.flv' -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -ab 128.k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -r 25 
-s 320x240 -vb 660.k -preset slow -f flv 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/streamTest' 


Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/streamTest':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 660 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 11025 Hz, mono, 16 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   15 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   27 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   40 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   52 fps= 24 q=27.0 size=       7kB time=00:00:00.-4 bitrate=-1362.0kbits
```

Comment: what errors?  this looks like proper ffmpeg output to me...

Comment: @Yuttadhammo It stops after fourth frame....Also if you see fourth frame again you will find `time` and `bitrate` with `-ve` values which messing things out their...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `-ab 128.k` and `-vb 660.k` shouldn't have periods in them, and also its just `-b`, not `-vb`... or am I missing something?  And if you use `-acodec copy` I don't see how you can specify an `-ab` audio bitrate or `-ar` either...

This might work better:

```
ffmpeg -re -i '/usr/share/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/avatar.flv' \
-vcodec libx264 -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -r 25 -s 320x240 -vb 660k -f \
flv 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/streamTest'
```

Comment: you're welcome, I was looking for an answer to a similar question that brought me here, so I know how it can be :)